# Remove values from CSV if not in list

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV table with 100s of rows and columns of numbers. I have another list which is a file of 1 column with some numbers that are in the table. Is there a way I can remove all values from the CSV that are not in the list?

I thought I could use `grep -f` for a list file but I am struggling as some values I want to remove are on the same row as values I want to keep.

E.g.

CSV table:

```
11,12,13 
11,10,12,13
```

list file:

```
13
11
```

Output:

```
11,,13 
11,,,,13
```

or alternatively

```
11,13 
11,13
```

Comment: the line `11,,,,13`  contains 5 fields but your input was contained 4 fields. what would be the output for a line like `113,111,110,130, 10,121,010`? In other word, you want exact match or partial match? please take a look in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a good MCVE

Comment: I am looking to remove numbers not in the list so 11,13 is right

Comment: You have received good answers, please indicate which one solved your problem. Stack exchange works in this way

Answer (score 2):

The following `awk` program assumes that your CSV fields contain no leading or trailing whitespace:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR{valid[$1];next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (!($i in valid)) {$i=""}}} 1' validvalues.txt input.csv
```

It will process first the `validvalues.txt` file with your valid values and then the actual CSV file.

- In the `BEGIN` section, the field separator for input and output is set to `,`.
- While processing the first file (indicated by `NR`, the global line counter, being equal to `FNR`, the per-file line counter), we simply record the allowed values as indices in the array `valid`, and otherwise skip processing to the next input line.
- When processing the second file, we iterate over all fields and check if the field content is part of the "array indices" of `valid`. If not, we set the field value to the empty field.
- The seemingly stray `1` prints the current line, including all modifications made so far.

Key point is that the `($i in valid)` test is a string-based comparison, so if either the column entries in the "valid values" file or the fields in the CSV file contain leading/trailing whitespace, the comparison will require that same whitespace to be also in the respective other file, which can lead to unwanted behavior.

**As mentioned by @glenn jackman** the program can be simplified as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR{valid[$1]=$1;next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {$i=valid[$i]}} 1' validvalues.txt input.csv
```

Here, we actually register the valid value also as "array value". The idea is that since invalid values have no entry in `valid`, `valid[$i]` will automatically evaluate to the empty string, while for a valid value it will return the value itself.

Please note however that the performance will be somewhat slower because it replaces "field values by themselves" unnecessarily, and that it will need more memory which can be an issue if the "valid values" file is large.

Comment: Nice! It can be a touch simpler. If you use `valid[$1] = $1` then the for loop body can be `$i = valid[$i]` with no "if" needed -- elements not in the array are replaced by an empty string.

Comment: @glennjackman Huh, that's really clever!

Comment: Thanks. It might be a touch slower because $0 gets rewritten every time a field is updated.

Comment: In addition to an unconditional `$i=valid[$i]` being slower as it changes every `$i` rather than just the ones that were in the list, it also adds every `$i` from input.csv to the array `valid[]` which could result in an additional significant slow down if `input.csv` contains a large number (i.e. millions) of unique values that aren't present in the list file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[,\n]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {ORS=RT} $0 in a' list file.csv
11,13
11,13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list, separated by pipe of your undesired values

```
list=$(<list.txt tr '\n' '|')
```

You will have `13|11|`.

And then run a [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) search and replace

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," -S put 'for (k in $*) {if($[k]!=~"^('"$list"')$"){$[k] = gsub($[k], $[k], "")}}' input.csv
```

to have

```
11,,13
11,,,13
```